Is it ethical for Victims Advocates to Be Paid By District Attorney Offices
I recently spent 2.5 years tied up in a case as a sexual assault victim. Since I had been intoxicated at the time I only had the knowledge that this person was over me and with his pants down, I asked the police the police the police to issue a restraining order from the person and when they asked him about the situation he claimed I invited him over and yes he did have sex me and yes I was unconscious. That’s all I was able to be told because they arrested him on 4 felony rape charges and 2 enhancements. For a majority of the trial I worked with a DDA who refused to back down even when I got nervous he might hurt me, she said it was her job to not only protect me but everyone else and she would not plea to anything less than a sexual registration charge. A year later she it promoted to a whole other division a new DDA who refused to sit down with me and talk to me about the case always mentioned as the trial neared we would speak.
I stressed my concerns to my victims advocate and mentioned to her several times her lack of interest in my case even after the police and the first D.A. after I circled back let me know there were no questions that this person did what he was charged with to me.
The day jury selection was to begin the DDA snuck a plea deal to the defend any and the judge even after telling me that wasn’t happening. The Victims Advocate when made aware of what happened notified me and I was at the courthouse in 10mins. The advocate listened to her lie to me, try and intimidate and then harrass me and refuse to me speak to the judge first all she could say was “I know and I’m so sorry”, she did give me a card for an attorney but ask I not tell anyone she did. Unfortunately, I understood the situation she was in because they both worked for the District Attorney and the DDA was much higher than her. Also, the plea was to Felony False Imprisonment, no additional jail time than the 4 days when he was arrested on $250k bail for the original charges.
My question is how can a victims advocate who works for one side or the other truly be able to protect the victim? Fortunately a family member witnessed the whole thing that transpired and prior to that with my concerns they were all in writing and she seemed very truthful to my concerns prior to the plea.
Why is this allowed?

It becomes really hard to follow, who did or said what. You also did not add a juristiction tag, so I don't think you will get any real useful answers. You just learned a very hard lesson, that only people on your payroll will actually work for you. So make the best of it and get a lawyer that you pay, to explain this whole thing and what your options are in your juristiction.

It is allowed because it's a logical place to fund victim's advocates.
Each state has its own requirements for including victims in plea and charging decisions.  Some states have zero requirements, others require a sign-off by victims prior to reduction of charges.  Your state should have  a victim's rights statement.  If you feel the prosecutor has not lived up to the rights you have in your state you should take this up with the office of the judge.
